# Javascript Regex for custom validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex

1) `[A-Z][a-z][0-9]` Must include uppercase & lowercase letters, numbers & special characters (except + and -).

2) Not more than 2 identical characters in a sequence (e.g., `AAxx1224!@` or `Password@123` or `Google#12` is not acceptable).

I have tried this but dont know how to check 2 identical characters.

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^%*()!&=]).*$
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far ?

Comment: The first condition sounds as if you want to allow any character but `+` and `-` in your input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew + and _ are not allowed

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla I edited my question please check

Answer (score 1):

You may add an additional `(?!.*(.)\1)` lookahead check to disallow consecutive characters and replace `.*` at the end with `[^_+]*` (or `[^-+]*` if you meant hyphens) to match any chars but `_` (or `-`) and `+`:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^*()!&=])[^_+]*$
  ^^^^^^^^^^                                                    ^^^^^
```

The `(?!.*(.)\1)` lookahead matches any 0+ chars other than line breaks chars and then captures these chars one by one and tries to match the identical char immediately after them (with the `\1` backreference). If the pattern is found, the whole match is failed.

Note that `[^_+]` may also match line breaks, but I guess it is not the problem here. Anyway, you  can add `\n\r` there to avoid matching them, too.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MGtsyU/1)

Comment: Try `(?!.*(.)\1.*(.)\2)`. Mind that will make it worse in terms of performance.